# Python Intel-MKL versions producing different results

Tags: python, intel-mkl

Our team is writing some for a project at work. Last week we realized we were getting slightly different, yet consistant results from varying computers. I believe I've tracked the problem down to the Intel-MKL library. Some computers are using a version from 2019 and some from 2020. Those with the same version are producing the same results.

Because we can't have users checking and updating their versions every time they use the code (this isn't just an internal tool), we need to ensure some sort of commonality in our calculations. How can I force the MKL library to use the same operations regardless of version from within my Python code? Is this possible? Thank you.